# Is running JSP similar to PHP?

Tags: java, php, jsp, web-applications

How do you run a JSP?

1. Is it similar to PHP wherein you only have to save it in an editor and reload the browser?
2. Or more like configure once, then after it's like PHP wherein it's just save and browser-reload?
3. Or there are a lot of in-betweens in saving and browser-reloading?

Answer (score 2):

I would say it's more like [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29). A JSP is first compiled in a class file and only then executed. **If you have configured your server to locate for the changes in JSPs** then only it will recompile the JSP while server is running.

Sometimes this mode of the server is called *development mode* and this process is called *hot deployment*. Until unless your server doesn't recompile the JSP, your changes in JSP file will not reflect through the server behavior in the browser.

Comment: It's no different than PHP then (almost). I wonder why people seem to say that PHP is advantageous because it's just "save and browser-reload", which brought me to the question - are others (more interestingly, JSP) not like that?

Comment: @Wap You are just comparing the end result. Think this way. JSP life cycle goes like JSP -> Servlet(Java) --> compile class file --> Execution. Its same difference as Some language like Basic and Java. If you write some logic, they may have same end result, but there internal behavior is entirely different. If still questions, let me know.

Comment: @Singh, thanks, but to be more accurate with the question, I was wondering if there are other "manually" done steps other than "save file" and "reload browser" when using JSP. The answer seems to be "save as class", "save as bytecode using container", then "reload browser", and they're all manually done. Is that right?

Comment: @Wap In that case(manual steps), `NO` provided your server is running in development mode.

Answer (score 1):

Server compile JSP to a Java class and based on the class content it's rendering information to the browser. So for the server it's again another class.

Comment: So it's more like (b)? Configurations...then after it's just "save (compile) to java class" then reload browser? Nothing in-betweens? Some say PHP has a great advantage in terms of its immediate feedback (save then reload)..so it's just a myth then?

Comment: it is more like 3 in my opinion, lot of things are going on. Java is not a interpreted language like php, it is first compiled to class and then executed. so when you save and reload jsp is compiled into a java class my container(tomcat) and compiles it and generates the byte code.

Comment: Oh, I see. But the "java class->byte code" is automatic and almost instantaneous and happens when I reload the browser? Or you have to manually tell the container(tomcat) to compile it to byte code, and only then can I reload the browser to have the new content?

Comment: it is manual, compiler can check for last saved time of file. Only thing you need to do is reload the browser.

Comment: Ah, there's an additional manual step then. I'll learn the language later then; seems arguably more robust than PHP, but save-reload of PHP is very convenient for development time. Upvoted